# GooglePAD and Chunking to Reduce .aab Size

Tags: android, google-play, asset-management, unreal-5

I would like to upload a large Android game to the Play Store. My .aab file is about 1.3 GB in size. When I try to upload it to the Play Store I get the following error message:

`The total download size of upfront Asset Packs in this App Bundle is 1292631053. Upfront Asset Packs can have a combined download size of 1073741824.`

I understand that I need to use GooglePAD. I’ve tried to set up the chunking, but now the main .aab is still as large as ever, but I do get several .pak files that add up to a combined file size of 1.3 GB.

Any advice?

Thanks.